# Google API Oauth2 - Server-side app, create Oauth token without user interaction or prompt

Tags: google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I've been having some problems trying to understand the Oauth requirements for Server-side applications which don't require User interaction when querying google API's.

Apologies if this seems obvious to most, but the issue I have is that all the examples and Oauth flows are based on prompting a user to either authorize which features the application has access to or authenticate the user with a google account before being granted a token and refresh token.

Does anyone have experience querying the Sheets API from a server side app without user interaction that could give me some pointers on how to create the Auth token?

I'll be using Javascript, AJAX and JSON to call the REST API.

Many thanks,
Billy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic

Comment: Thanks pinoyyid, it's frustrating to know the setting was right under my nose, when I was playing around with Oauth playground for an hour. Thanks very much though, saved me a lot more wasted time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks pinoyyid, having searched this site for and hour and playing around with Oauth playground for better part of an hour, it's frustrating to know the answer was right under my nose in the settings!

Thanks again, really appreciate you pointing me to [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic).

For those reading this in the future the link in the comment above will solve your problem, to summarise, you can use your own app settings by going to the google Oauth playground and on the top right select the settings (picture of a cog/gear) and ticking the box to use your app details, enter the client ID and client secret, job done.

Cheers,
Billy